# How to change the title of an Iframe dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show some video files in an Iframe for our company web site. Whenever the user clicks on a video link it will be shown inside an Iframe. I used a Javascript file to perform this action. If I host my videos on you tube, you tube show the title of video.But the javascript I used only change the content of the iframe. I need to show the title of the video files somewhere above the Iframe.
The javascript file I use is this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeVideoUrl(url)
{
document.getElementById("video_iframe").src = url;
}
</script>
```

and in  I wrote this :

```
<a class="links" href="JavaScript:ChangeVideoUrl('https://..something.');"> text</a>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "title"? What is the html?

Comment: `iframe` does not have a title attribute. What is it that you're looking for?

Comment: @BrianS Yes, it does, but it doesn't seem relevant...

Comment: @m59, Sorry. You're technically correct, as title is a global attribute. But it's not going to do anything useful for an `iframe`

Comment: You still haven't mentioned what "title" you want to update...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the actual title of the iframe with `iframeReference.contentDocument.title = 'some title'`. If you want to change an html title like a `h1` tag, you can get the reference to it and set its `textContent`. See below.

**Sample Markup:**

```
  <button id="myBtn">Change Iframe</button>
  <h1 id="h1Title">Iframe Title</h1>
  <iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>
```

**Sample JavaScript:**

```
var myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
var myIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
var h1Title = document.getElementById('h1Title');

myBtn.addEventListener('click', changeIframe);

function changeIframe() {
  myIframe.contentDocument.title = 'New title!';
  h1Title.textContent = 'New Title!';
}
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/ukoYOzOz/1/edit)**

As you have now updated your question with your code, there is more to say.

First, inline js (JavaScript inside your html elements) is bad. Read some of these results: https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F

Instead, follow my example and get element references and attach event listeners to them. You can store your data on the element and pull it from there if you want to.

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/ukoYOzOz/2/edit)**

**Markup:**

```
<div class="links">
  <a data-src="a/video" data-title="A video!">Click to Play: A video!</a>
  <a data-src="some/title" data-title="Some Title!">Click to Play: Some Title!</a>
  <a data-src="another/title" data-title="Another Title!">Click to Play: Another Title!</a>
</div>
<h1 id="h1Title">Iframe Title</h1>
<iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var myIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
var h1Title = document.getElementById('h1Title');
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.links a');

for (var i=0; i<links.length; ++i) {
  addClickFunc(links[i], i);
}

function addClickFunc(elem, i) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var title = elem.getAttribute('data-title');
    var src = elem.getAttribute('data-src');
    changeIframe(title, src);
  });  
}


function changeIframe(title, src) {
  myIframe.src = src;
  myIframe.contentDocument.title = title;
  h1Title.textContent = title;
}
```

Comment: But I do not need a button

Comment: @user3026373 then don't use the button =D I was just giving a demonstration.

Comment: Is there anyway I can do it without button? I edited my question, would you be able to have a look, please? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming some heading for title. You can do this also by javascript.

Give the id for the tag that holding the title of iframe.
Using javascript change the text in that when user click's on video link(chnage innerHTML).

Comment: I am not familiar that much with Javascript, would you be able please to do it and put it as demo here? I really appreciate it.