# Adding title to dynamically generated iframe

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe

I'm generating the iframe dynamically and adding a title for that but instead of the given title I'm getting the Action Method name as the title. My code is:

```
("#modalBody").empty().append('<iframe title="This is the title" id="iframeID"></iframe>');
$("#iframeID").attr("src", "../Employee/GetEmployeeDetails?empID=" + empID);
$('#empModal').modal('show');
```

Title is coming as: `GetEmployeeDetails` instead of `'This is the title'`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:
I found one similar question but here the iframe has been generated dynamically while in that question iframe was not generated dynamically.

Edit -2
This is also giving the same result:

```
 ("#modalBody").empty().append('<iframe title="This is the title" id="iframeID"></iframe>');
    $("#modalBody iframe").contentDocument.title = 'My New title!';
 $("#iframeID").attr("src", "../Employee/GetEmployeeDetails?empID=" + empID); $('#empModal').modal('show');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the title of an Iframe dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119424/how-to-change-the-title-of-an-iframe-dynamically)

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Yes, I've seen that one before posting the question, that question is little different, here I'm generating the iframe dynamically. I tried but couldn't solve the issue. :)

Comment: Sorry may I ask why an Iframe?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot seem to replicate what you have posted but the below markup is working for me:

**HTML**

```
<div id="modalBody">
  <div id="somemarkuphere">

  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#modalBody").html('<iframe title="This is the title" id="iframeID"></iframe>');
   $("#modalBody iframe").attr("src", "../Employee/GetEmployeeDetails?empID=" + 1);
  $("#modalBody iframe").attr("title", 'My New title!');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/12781/